# Network troubleshooting

Tags: networking

I'm new on here but I'm sure my network problem isn't new and so hope I can get a bit of help .

I have a router in the office with 3 pc's connected, and a length of ethernet cable, less than 100m, which runs to another part of the building straight into a 8 port switch, call it sw1. Connected to sw1 are 2 wifi access points and another length of cable going into another switch, call it sw2.  Sw2 has a tv and another wifi access point connected to it.

My problem seems to be with the cable going into sw2, before using sw2 I could connect a laptop into that cable and it works fine, but the tv would work and sometimes wouldn't. Even connecting to the access point on sw2 is a bother with intermittent connection problems using mobile phones.

All the access points can be seen from the router side of the network even when I can't get a connection on the sw2 side of the network.

Any insight into this problem would be much appreciated.

---

I take it it is ok to setup the network the way I have cascading the switches and connecting access points or I think you would have mentioned that. I have used several different switches for sw2 and that part of the network always ents up the same after a time - not data.

Comment: It sounds as though you've already located the problem to the cable. What happened when you tried putting in another cable, or when you tried moving the existing cable to a new port?

Comment: Hi thanks Jenny, The cable runs through an attic and down the outside of the building so it would not be easy to replace. It works fine with the laptop I've tried one of those cheap ethernet testers on the cable to test for continuity and the order of the wiring and it is okay. Its driving me nuts, it can work fine for a day or more then even though devices will connect there is no data.

Comment: I thought that when you said *problem seems to be with the cable* that it was the cable that was the issue. But if there are problems with the access point as well as with all the devices connected to the switch, I'd focus on the switch. Switch it out and see what happens?

Comment: "_The cable runs through an attic and down the outside of the building_" Is it a proper outdoor cable? The regular cable you buy is not outdoor rated, and _any_ moisture will change the dielectric properties of the cable. There are also laws and codes relating to any outdoor cabling (proper grounding and bonding, outdoor cabling cannot extend more than 50 feet inside a building, etc.). You can get the building red-tagged for occupation, and be civilly and criminally liable in case of something like a fire.

Answer (score 2):

Your cable run is most probably problematic, you state under 100m, but please be sure as 100m is the maximum allowed for the cable length before getting error in it.

Please test it and make sure it's ok with a cable tester, not just plugin it in a computer to see if it see the network.

If some pin are not detected the detection would switch to a 100mb speed in example, as such the switch might have difficulty to use the cable run, unlike your laptop.

> Maximum length. When used for 10/100/1000BASE-T, the maximum allowed
>   length of a Cat 6 cable is up to **100 meters (328 ft)**. This
>   consists of 90 meters (295 ft) of solid "horizontal" cabling between
>   the patch panel and the wall jack, plus 5 meters (16 ft) of stranded
>   patch cable between each jack and the attached device.

Comment: Thanks yagmoth, The cable that is connects to sw1 is not a problem its the one connecting from sw1 to sw2 which is the problem and that is much shorter than the other cable. Must be about 60 feet

Comment: @PaulH shorter, but tested ?

Comment: I think I'm going to retest the cable and I just remembered the cable connects into a socket faceplate on the wall so I'll swap that out to just in case its dodgy and if that doesn't work I'll take your advice and change the cable when we get some nice weather.